# Como criar um site estático

Tags: html

Estou a desenvolver um site só com HTML e CSS. Quero que o tamanho estático seja este:

```
#tudo{
    width: 1024px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left; /* "remédio" para o hack do IE */  
}
```

O problema é quando o ecrã é menor o site desconfigura em vez de se manter igual nos 1024px. O que fazer?

Quando fica num ecra menor que 1024px fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pode explicar melhor o que quer dizer com estático?

Comment: David, eu daria uma olhada na ideia de layouts responsivos. Talvez o bom e velho bootstrap possa te ajudar ;)

Comment: Agradeço a sua dica. Neste momento estou a praticar com técnicas da velha escola. Só depois num outro site irei abordar essa área.

Comment: @David aconselho estudar sobre CSS Media Queries!

Comment: Por acaso voce definiu as propriedades dos botoes(<code>width, margin e padding</code>) em pixels tambem ou em porcentagem? Está usando float left nos botões?<br>
Seria bom mostrar o html e o css deles tambem, pois senão fica dificil te orientar em alguma coisa.

Comment: Acrescentar um `min-width:1024px` faz com que ele mostre uma barra horizontal em vez de bagunçar.

Comment: bacco você resolveu o meu problema obrigado :)

Answer (score 3):

quando o "ecrã" (tela para pt-br) é menor que a largura do seu `div` `#tudo`, mude a propriedade CSS `width` para `max-width` e assim, o conteúdo vai se ajustar à larguras menores.

https://jsfiddle.net/4nnkfuLt/

```
#tudo {
  max-width: 1024px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Não resolveu o meu problema. Pensei que tinha resolvido mas não. A solução já foi dita aqui - devo acrescentar o min-width de 1024px. Da forma que você está a indicar teria de criar width para a caixa nas css. Mas valeu pela ajuda, mesmo :) Obrigado!

Comment: não acho que seja bom ter uma barra horizontal para seus usuários, hum... se esta apenas estudando tudo bem, mas se for para outras pessoas acessarem você não pode deixar essa barra lá, o melhor mesmo é que o container se adapte ao conteudo e quando a tela for menor, o conteudo se espreme mas nao cria barra horizontal

Comment: Leandro você tem toda a razão. Estou a dar os primeiros pasos na prática. Vou com calma. O importante para já é que ele cumpre regras. Depois posso criar uma folha de estilo para dispositivos moveis. Para já estou a aprender na prática vendo como os elementos reagem. Obrigado pelo conselho :)

Answer (score 0):

Tente colocar um overflow na sua janela do navegador. No caso no seu body e faça o teste,

`body{
    overflow: scroll;
}`